# Reference a component in a different xml file

Tags: android, xml

I am doing like an app to split receipts (just for fun) and this is kind of my first android studio/app project.

Is it possible to reference a component in one xml layout from another one to use it as a constraint? As you can see here in the picture: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2p4T.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2p4T.png)
I want that the person text and the sum text are lined up with the checkboxes.

I tried the following in my code for my activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseFileBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="chooseFile"
        android:text="@string/btn_filechoose"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_finn_sum"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/person2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chooseFileBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chooseFileBtn"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/checkBox_1"/> This does not work here

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_basti_sum"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/person1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chooseFileBtn" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sumTotal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseFileBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_sumTotal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_sum1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/sumTotal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sum2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chooseFileBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_sum2"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/sumTotal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/person1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for the items in the recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="@string/txt_item_name"
        android:gravity="start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/txt_item_price"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can only reference view IDs that are within the same XML file. There only is a workaround coming to my mind:

Position the checkboxes and the labels relatively within their containers, so that their positions match at the end. You can achieve this by using [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline). You can position Guidelines inside the XML by providing percentage of width values. Then, you can align views to those Guidelines. 
Do this within your Activity layout file to position the labels, for example at 70% and 90% of the width. Then, change the root layout of your Recyclerview items to `ConstraintLayout` and also position Guidelines there similarly. Position the checkboxes at the Guidelines.

As a result, the labels and checkboxes should be somewhat at the same position, and also will be at different screen sizes. You might need to tweak around with padding a little bit to get better results.

Here is an example how to position a Guideline and then align a view to it:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/guideline"
             app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8"
             android:orientation="vertical"/>
         <Button
             android:text="Button"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/button"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
             android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I may try that. The solution I got right now was just trying until it somewhat fits xD